# Button not triggered on blogger

Tags: html, jquery, blogger

I got this code for redirecting a form to WhatsApp. I have tested it on an HTML page, and it works well, but when I move it to Blogger HTML Template Editor, the button cannot be triggered and nothing happens. I thought it was about the Jquery library on the blogger was not installed, but when I add the CDN link, it still not working. Or is there something missing from my code, or what's the problem?

```
   <head>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <style>
        .panel{border:none;}
        
        .panel-heading
        {
            border:1px #212121 !important;          
            border-radius: 0px;
            background-color: #212121 !important; 
            color: #fff !important; 
            padding:20px 15px !important;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        
        .btn-success {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #5cb85c;
            border-color: #4cae4c;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 600;
            padding: 8px 14px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
<body style='background-color:transparent;'>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-success">
                <div class="panel-body">
                
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name* :" id="name">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="company" class="form-control" placeholder="Company/Organization* :" id="company">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <textarea name="product_description" class="form-control" rows="3" id="product_description" placeholder="Message* :"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class='col-md-12'>
                        <div id="text-info"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button align='center' class="btn btn-success sending">Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
    <script>
    $(document).on('click','.sending', function(){
        /* Inputan Formulir */
        var input_name                  = $("#name").val(),
            input_company               = $("#company").val(),
            input_email                 = $("#email").val(),
            input_phone                 = $("#phone").val(),
            input_product               = $("#product").val(),
            input_product_description   = $("#product_description").val();
     
        /* Pengaturan Whatsapp */
        var walink      = 'https://web.whatsapp.com/send',
            phone       = '6282200000000',
            text        = '/ Website Contact Form',
            text_yes    = 'Redirecting you to WhatsApp',
            text_no     = 'Please fill this form to start your booking.';
     
        /* Smartphone Support */
        if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            var walink = 'whatsapp://send';
        }
     
        if(input_name != "" && input_phone != "" && input_product != ""){
            /* Whatsapp URL */
            var checkout_whatsapp = walink + '?phone=' + phone + '&text=' + text + '%0A%0A' + 
                'Name: ' + input_name + '%0A' +
                'Perusahaan/Organisasi: ' + input_company + '%0A' +
                'Message: ' + input_product_description
                
            /* Whatsapp Window Open */
            window.open(checkout_whatsapp,'_blank');
            document.getElementById("text-info").innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-success">'+text_yes+'</div>';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("text-info").innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger">'+text_no+'</div>';
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe blogger has blocked some javascript functions in template edition, open a new window is not the best way to do this,

try to put the link into a `<a>` tag with `target="_blank"`

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attributes

```
const a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
a.setAttribute("href", "your whatsapp link");
a.click();
```

Or generate a a link as the submit form button, to do that, you will have to update the href prop of the link (displayed as submit button) every time the user update the data of the form